# Monix task handle failure for list of futures

Tags: scala, task, future, monix

How can I handle the failure during the asynchronous execution of the task? I.e. at least print the stack trace and shut down. The code below seems to wait forever for input > 5

```
val things = Range(1, 40)
  implicit val scheduler = monix.execution.Scheduler.global
  def t(i:Int) = Task.eval {
      Try{
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        val result = i + 1
        if(result > 5){
          throw new Exception("asdf")
        }
        // i.e. write to file, that's why unit is returned
        println(result) // Effect
        "Result"
      }
    }
    val futures = things.map(e=> t(e))
  futures.foreach(_.runToFuture)
```

### edit

trying:

```
futures.foreach(_.runToFuture.onComplete {
    case Success(value) =>
      println(value)
    case Failure(ex) =>
      System.err.println(ex)
      System.exit(1)
  })
```

will not stop the computation.
How can I log the stack trace and cancel the ongoing computations and stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more idiomatic approach would be to use `Observable` instead of `Task` since it is dealing with list of data (I'm assuming that's the use case since it is shown in the question).

```
 val obs = Observable
  .fromIterable(Range(1, 40))
  .mapEval(i =>
    if (i + 1 > 5) Task.raiseError(new Exception("Error")) // will stop the stream
    else Task.delay(println(i)) // Or write to file in your case
  )
  .completedL
  .runToFuture


obs
  .recover {
    case NonFatal(e) => println("Error")
  }
```

Alternatively, you can also signal the error with `Either` which leads to better type safety, since you'll need to handle the `Either` result.

```
val obs = Observable
  .fromIterable(Range(1, 40))
  .mapEval(i =>
    if (i + 1 > 5) Task.pure(Left("Error"))
    else Task.delay(println(i)).map(_ => Right(())) // Or write to file in your case
  )
  .takeWhileInclusive(_.isRight) // will also emit the failing result
  .lastL
  .runToFuture


obs.map {
  case Left(err) => println("There's an error")
  case _ => println("Completed successfully")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problems has 2 parts:

- Making the tasks cancellable.
- Cancelling the siblings when one task fails.

#### Making the task cancellable

Monix has [BooleanCancelable](https://monix.io/docs/3x/execution/cancelable.html#booleancancelable) which would allow you to set the result of `isCancelled` to `true` when the `cancel` is called.

`cancel` also needs to call `Thread.interrupt` to wake it up when `Thread.sleep` is running.  Otherwise the `sleep` will run through its course.  However this will throw [InterruptedException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) within your task.  That needs to be handled.

#### Cancelling the siblings

There is [CompositeCancelable](https://monix.io/docs/3x/execution/cancelable.html#compositecancelable).  It seems like the use case for `CompositeCancellable` it for calling `cancel` from the parent task.  So once the `CompositeCancellable` is built (ie. all tasks are constructred):

- Either a reference of this must be made available to each task, so the failing task can call `cancel` on it.  (Note that this is a sort of circular reference, better avoided)
- Or parent task (or code) is made aware when a sub-task fails and it calls `cancel`.  (This would avoid circular reference)

Another way to notify sibling tasks is to use an [AtomicBoolean](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) and frequently check it (sleep 10 milliseconds instead of 1000).  When one task fails it would then set this boolean so other tasks can stop their execution.  This of course does not involve `Cancellable`.  (And it's kind of a hack, better to use monix scheduler)

#### Note

Is it a good idea to call `Thread.sleep` within a `Task`?  I think this would prevent another task to use that thread.  I think using scheduler to add delays and composing those sub-tasks is the way to utilize the thread-pool most effectively.

Comment: Using sleep was just a dummy example. Obviously you are correct about this.

Comment: The approach with `CompositeCancellable ` sounds best. But how can I invoke cancel? In the `    case Failure(ex) =>` I only can get the `Exception`, not the `Cancelable`. Could you add a minimal example using the `Or parent task` approach?

Comment: I have linked [documentation for CompositeCancellable](https://monix.io/docs/3x/execution/cancelable.html#compositecancelable), second example there should help.  Basically you add `Cancellable`s to a `CompositeCancellable` via `+=` and then call `cancel` on the composite.

Comment: I do not yet understand how to map a `Task` into `Cancellable` and keep the reference cancellable. https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/580518df9b3c8b5a978e736af757ac21 outlines my approach in more detail.

Comment: [`Task.cancellable`](https://monix.io/api/3.0/monix/eval/Task$.html) seems to construct a cancellable task but frankly I also haven't wrapped my head around it.  Example on that page is quite noisy.  I would also like to see a working example.